# How to schedule a list of meetings in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, scheduling

For some projects, I often have to schedule a serie of meeting (one each month during 3 months, as aan example).
Is there anything allowing me to automatically create that list of meetings as soon as the project is started without having to create each one by hand ?

Comment: Does [this help center post](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37115?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) answer your question?

Comment: @WebAppUser Unfortunatly not, because I want those events to have different content (but indeed it could be a workaround)

Comment: There are *thousands* of options. Many of them are possible thanks to the Google Calendar API. Look at the Google Workspace Marketplace, search for no-code, low-code apps, look for automation applications, ...

Comment: I think you need to [edit] your question to be more specific about what you want to do. What is it about creating three meetings that is so much work that you need an automated solution?  Are you starting from PM software? What about copying the meetings and changing the dates?